# M2Mqtt android/xamarin for some reason not working anymore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, mqtt

I built an xamarin cross platform mobile application last summer.  We were waiting for the hardware to be ready for us to deploy the app.

Now everything is ready I kept a copy of the application on my one drive.

I copied the application from my one drive onto my development machine last week I have been working with it in debug mode.

Yesterday I tried to compile in release mode and all of a sudden my

using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;

grayed out and show error could not be found.  Now I can't get anything to work the way it did even in debug mode all my mqtt commands are showing an error.

I tried reinstalling the nuget packages but I get error tying to compile to ......... not available in package see author

I just don't understand what happend and why

[image]

Please let me know if you have any ideas, from what I've read it may be because I moved the project from a different folder.  Please help

Comment: What NuGet packages are you referring to? Can you provide a link at the minimum?

Comment: m2mqtt v4.3.0 by Paolo Patierno.  It is a c# mqtt client that has worked great for me up to this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did originally was find m2mqtt.mono.dll which worked fine for a while until I found some bugs that were fixed in more resent commits.

I have now gotten my hands on M2Mqtt.Net.dll which I just added to my Xamarin project and it seems to be working good.

I went to paho.mqtt.m2mqtt master.  Downloaded git opened sln in Visual Studio 2017, built solution and got M2Mqtt.Net.dll from M2Mqtt/obj/debug folder and added reference to it in my project.

I'll keep you advised if I have any problems

Answer (score 0):

You need `M2Mqtt for .Net  MQTT` with `uPLibrary`. M2Mqtt will provide **M2Mqtt.dll** to support `uPLibrary`. You need to add **M2Mqtt.dll** reference in your project.

Please check [M2Mqtt for .Net : MQTT client for Internet of Things & M2M communication](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/M2Mqtt-MQTT-client-library-ac6d3858).